# centerInside does not scale Drawable to ImageView

Tags: android

The description of `centerInside`

> Scale the image uniformly (maintain the image's aspect ratio) so that both dimensions (width and height) of the image will be equal to or less than the corresponding dimension of the view (minus padding).

I imagine this description means the image should scale to the edge closest to it in it's view container.

This little red square in my assets folder does not appear to be scaling

[image]

Here is my `main_activity.xml`

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/redSquare"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:background="#00ffff"
        />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

And here I'm setting the drawable to the image view

```
ImageView redSqaure;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);

    //...

    try {

        InputStream ims = getAssets().open("redSquare.png");
        Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(ims, null);

        // Setting the drawable to image view
        redSqaure.setImageDrawable(d);

        ims .close();

    } catch(IOException ex) { 

    }

}
```

Any help? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

yes, it does what it stated:

> Scale the image uniformly (maintain the image's aspect ratio) so that both dimensions (width and height) of the image will be equal to or less than the corresponding dimension of the view (minus padding).

It maintains your image and size is less than your parent view. If you need the image to fit your view, just add this line in your xml:

```
android:scaleType="fitCenter" // change this flag as well.
android:adjustViewBounds="true" //Set this to true if you want the ImageView to adjust its bounds to preserve the aspect ratio of its drawable.
```

Comment: The xml attribute you shared does not appear to have the effect I wanted

Comment: Looks like it might be working, only problem is that app bar is over lapping the image view

Comment: Okay, yes it's working, thank you. However, I don't understand why `centerInside` does not work as it's supposed to.